# How to get number of written records in spark structured streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, metrics

I have a few structured streams configured in a single spark session. I need to know how many records were read and written in each stream.
For example, I have these two streams:

1. read-s3 -> transform -> write-s3
2. read-s3 -> transform -> write-db

I know about using SparkListener().onTaskEnd() but at that point I don't have a query name and `taskEnd.taskMetrics().outputMetrics().recordsWritten()` is always 0 so it's not an option.

Another way is to use accumulators in dataset.map() to calculate it incrementally. But then it's not a number of written records but records to be written (if sink not fail).

Besides that I tried to use StreamingQueryListener (which I use to get `numInputRows`) but I couldn't find any metrics regarding number of written records.

Is there a possibility to get this kind of metrics?

Comment: Is it still about [custom sink](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48466019/8371915)?

Comment: No. That post was about fixing a number of input rows but here I'm asking about number of output records and it doesn't matter which sink to use. Of course, having a custom sink I can add those metrics by my own but what to do if I use FileStreamSink?

Comment: There was a bug in FileStreamSink (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-23288) that is fixed in version 2.3.1

Comment: Please post it as an answer (https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). It will be more visible to the future visitors, and will allow to resolve the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was [a bug in FileStreamSink](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-23288) that is fixed in version 2.3.1.

As a workaround used [accumulators](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#accumulators) in a map function to count number of records just before writing to a sink.